# Will kubuntu support snap packages?

Tags: kubuntu, 16.04, snap

Does Kubuntu 16.04 support snap packages?

Comment: All official 16.04 flavors should be supporting snap. I know that Lubuntu and Xubuntu do so.

Comment: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/13/snaps-for-classic-ubuntu/

Comment: However, the snap infrastructure `snapd` is not installed by default, at least in Lubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

Snap packages work natively on all officially supported Ubuntu flavors, starting with 16.04 and later, in other words snap packages work on all currently supported versions.

All installed snap packages except for the core snap depend on two packages, one of which is the core snap.

1. *snapd*
2. *core* - (the core snap) which is automatically downloaded and installed when the first installed snap package is installed